# How can I set some part of matrix in mathnet according to a condition

Tags: c#, matrix, mathnet-numerics

I am new in mathnet and I want to know how I can set some part of matrix in C#.

For example I have ed is matrix and I want to run this convert this command from matlab to c#. How I can do this?

```
ed(10*ed<100)=50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
ed.MapInplace(x => 10 * x < 100 ? 50 : x, Zeros.Include);
```

The documentation of Math.NET matrices can be found at:
[Matrices and Vectors](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. it is something which I need.